# Can one track the usage of a shared resource from google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Does anyone here know if you on Google Drive somehow can track if a public shared link to a file have been used?

That is, the resource have been downloaded, viewed or otherwise "touched"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, and no

**No**: For consumer accounts.

**Yes**: For within a domain for Google Apps unlimited account, you can using the Admin API to receive view events.

Find the documentation here: [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive), relevant except follows.

## Retrieve Google Drive events by event name

To retrieve a report of all instances of specific event type such as creating or editing a document, use the following GET HTTP request using the authorization token described in the authorization documentation. The userKey is the primary email address of the user in the report. The eventName can either be a access or acl_change event. For the eventName information, see the Drive event names reference information. For more information about the request's query strings and the response properties, see the API Reference. For readability, the following example is formatted with line returns:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all
/applications/drive?endTime=a date&startTime=a date
&filters=event name parameter relational operator parameter value,...
&actorIpAddress=user's IP address
&maxResults=maximum number of events returned on a response page
&eventName=either a view or edit event
```

Comment: Dammit. I only have a consumer plan for now. Thanks anyway.